# jQuery hide only THIS replies

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this jQuery code here:

```
$(".replies_hide").click(function(e) {
    $(".replies_show").show(); // This is only button code. Not replies
    $(".replies").hide(300); // I need to hide only these replies. Not all replies
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

When I click "show replies" button it shows me the replies of the specific comment. But when I click "replies_hide" it closes all replies at once. How to only hide the replies that I've just opened up ?

HTML:

```
       <ul class="list-unstyled replies">
        <a class="replies_hide" href="#">Hide replies</a>
        @foreach($com->reply as $reply)
        <li style="margin-left: 5%">
       <img src="http://flipbit.co.uk/content/images/blog/build-avatar.jpg" style="height: 30px">
       <strong>{{$reply->user->name}}</strong> 
       {!! strtr(strip_tags($reply->reply), $emotes) !!}<br>
       <small>{{$reply->created_at}}</small>
       @if(Auth::user()->id == $reply->user_id)
       <a href="/trinti-atsakyma/{{$reply->id}}">Trinti</a>
       @endif
       </li>
       @endforeach    
       </ul>
```

Comment: The problem is that it only hides the button called "hide replies" but not the replies

Comment: can you add the html markup?

Comment: Can you please post your HTML?

Comment: Yes, I've updated my answer

Comment: use `$(this).closest(".replies").hide(300);` problem is how are you going to show it again ? because `replies` is parent of `replies_hide` so use `.closest()` or `.parent('.replies')`

Comment: i suggest you make the `.replies` child of `.replies_hide` then use `$(this).find('.replies').toggle()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your HTML markup, it seems that you want to hide only the `ul` block containing the `hide` button you clicked and the related replies so you'll need to find the closest `ul` block to the button you clicked.

To do that, you can use:

```
$(this).closest(".replies").hide(300);
```

It will get the first element that matches the selector by testing the element itself and traversing up through its ancestors in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because you are hiding all the element of replies class. You have to hide only the html element on which you are. Try this:

```
$(this).hide();
```